# Header text shifted in TreeView control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

I am playing with WPF TreeView control and facing strange problem.
When I add TreeView items programmatically all working correct, but in case I have added items through binding - I have Items with gap in header:

[image]

furthermore, this gap is only one "sensitive" part of the TreeItem's line. I cant select item by clicking on the text, it can be selected only if I click on the gap area.
Here is my code:

```
namespace WPFTreeViewExperience
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Data item interface
    /// </summary>
    public interface IMyTree
    {
        string Title { get; set; }
        List<IMyTree> Items { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hierarchical data model
    /// </summary>
    public class MyTreeLevel : IMyTree
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public List<IMyTree> Items { get; set; }

        public MyTreeLevel(string Title, params MyTreeLevel[] Items)
        {
            this.Title = Title;

            this.Items = new List<IMyTree>();

            foreach (MyTreeLevel item in Items)
            {
                this.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Viewmodel
    /// </summary>
    public class MyTreeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private void NotifyChanges(string PropName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropName));
        }
    }

    private List<MyTreeLevel> _Tree;

    public List<MyTreeLevel> MyTree
    {
        get
        {
            return _Tree;
        }

        set
        {
            _Tree = value;
            NotifyChanges("MyTree");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MyTreeViewModel()
    {
        List<MyTreeLevel> simpleTree = new List<MyTreeLevel>();

            simpleTree.Add(new MyTreeLevel("1-0", new MyTreeLevel("1-1"),
                                          new MyTreeLevel("1-2",
                                                                new MyTreeLevel("1-2-1"),
                                                                new MyTreeLevel("1-2-2")
                                                                ),
                                          new MyTreeLevel("1-3")));

            simpleTree.Add(new MyTreeLevel("2-0", new MyTreeLevel("2-1"),
                                          new MyTreeLevel("2-2",
                                                                new MyTreeLevel("2-2-1"),
                                                                new MyTreeLevel("2-2-2"),
                                          new MyTreeLevel("2-3"))));

            MyTree = simpleTree;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {        
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                TreeExample.DataContext = new MyTreeViewModel();
            }
        }
    }
```

and my XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTreeViewExperience.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTreeViewExperience"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView Name="TreeExample" ItemsSource="{Binding MyTree}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DataType="{x:Type local:MyTreeLevel}">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Title}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What is wrong with my binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that ItemTemplate should be something like this:

```
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DataType="{x:Type local:MyTreeLevel}">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Margin="0" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
        </Grid>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: It is working! But its also working without `Grid`. Can you explain me the trick with Grid tag you planned to achieve?

Comment: Yes, it works without Grid. I use Grid if I want add something else. Icon, for example